# JS - Date check

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to check if a date (from a `date input`) is different than today :

```
  <input type="date" id="date">
```

Here my JS :

```
 var selectedDate = document.getElementById('date');
        var now = new Date();
        if (selectedDate < now) {
        alert("Some alert!");
            return;
        }
```

It doesn't work - any idea why ?
Thanks

Comment: You're comparing a DOM node to a Date.

Comment: `document.getElementById('date')` will return a DOM Element. You need to get its content first using `.value`

Comment: change `var selectedDate = document.getElementById('date');` to `var selectedDate = document.getElementById('date').value;`

Comment: @lxe the element is an input so it would be value, not innerHTML

Comment: @SpencerMay oops. Yeah `.value` then.

Comment: `var selectedDate = document.getElementById('date').value;
var date = new Date(selectedDate);` It works thanks!

Comment: If I may believe this [w3 doc](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html#input.date-interface) then `.value` is a string. Apparently there is a property `.valueAsDate` which gives you the value as an actual Date instance. Under chrome. If [mozilla's page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#Specifications) is correct then input type=date is still not implemented in Firefox and IE. I hope you realize this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the solution :

```
  var selectedDate = document.getElementById('date').value;
        var date = new Date(selectedDate);
        var now = new Date();
        if (date < now) {
        alert("You picked an invalid date!");
            return;
        }
```